Spring Boot 3: disable JPA, but not JDBC, using multiple data sources
I am trying to set up two DataSources in my project, out of which none are primary. Both are accessed using JdbcTemplates, which I also configure manually, and it is working just fine.
However, the application context refuses to initialize unless I set one of the DataSources are primary due to some inner workings of EntityManager autoconfiguration.
Without a primary Datasource I get the following:
WARN 668108 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaSharedEM_entityManagerFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument
Followed by:
ERROR 668108 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

A component required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

I was trying to get to the heart of the issue, but to no avail. Excluding HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration didn't help. I would rather disable the JPA configuration completely rathar than resort to workarounds. For example, I don't even need the JPA repository scanning, since I don't intend to use them at this moment, but it still happens.
Has anyone else tackled this issue?

remove spring data dependency and use spring data JDBC or JDBC Api.

@kushparsaniya surely a similar effect could be achieved by simply excluding certain autoconfiguration classes, the question is which ones

But if you don't want to use hibernate than simply, using spring data jdbc is fine. and don 't overwhelm with entity and other stuff.
